# Which is aggregate root. Recipient or Cost ? DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, one-to-many, aggregateroot

I'm creating an application to analyze my expenses. I want to implement in a DDD way.
My 2 main entities are :
CounterPart(Recipient/Sender) and Expense(Cost/Income)

[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKIWJ.png)

It seems logical to take CounterPart as an aggregate root but I need to do a lot of actions on Expense directly like marking it as a daily, monthly, ... expense.

Can I only interact on expense using the counterPart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Aggreggate Root`  in `DDD` is driven by your Business requirements. You need to have a good understanding of business before deciding your aggreggate root.

In your case, there is one to many relationship between `CounterPart` and `Expense`. Can  `Expense` exist outside of `CounterPart`? If not, it probably makes sense to have `CounterPoint` as your `Aggreggate Root`.

If you need to manipulate your `Expense`, you would then need to expose operations such as `AddExpenseToCounterPart`, `SetExpenseToDaily` etc  on `CounterPart`.

If, however, your `Domain` is simple (or `anaemic`) without any complex business rules.I would ask why to even go for DDD?

Comment: An Expense cannot exist without a counterpart. I currently implemented it without DDD, but I was wondering if it would be better to implement it DDD. 

The Domain is pretty simple, so maybe it's indeed best to leave it as is.